# DDD Fetching List of Roots

Tags: domain-driven-design

So, I've got a WCF service that accepts commands and maps them to calls into the domain services layer.  When doing write type of commands to the domain, this pattern is nearly perfect.

What I'm wondering is how everyone is doing reads, more specifically, getting lists of aggregates from the model for display.  As I stated, I have a WCF service that calls into the service layer.  Currently, I have a method on my service that returns a list of aggregate roots.  Somehow, this feels a bit dirty.  I'm polluting my domain services with GetByXXXX kind of methods.

I'm looking for a bit of guidance on the search and retrieval of domain objects through the application services layer.

Edit:

Thinking and reading a bit more, is it appropriate to directly use a repository in the application layer to handle fetching of entities?

Comment: I use repositories in the application layer. Some detach work needs to be done when invovles lazy-loading stuffs. If you have plethora of specific query methods, you may define a criteria object instead.

Comment: Yes, repository is a natural place for finder methods. No need to build another layer of complexity (app->service->repository instead of app->repository). Widely used pattern "Relaxed layered system" allows usage of all layers beneath the layer in question. So, you could also use repository inside your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with a simple query layer that returns a `DataTable` for collections and a `DataRow` for 1 item.  For something more structured I would use a DTO.  So all your `GetByXXX` methods could sit in the query layer.

Comment: DataTables are way too heavy to return over a network service.  They contain database metadata.  Even working with DataTables without a network service, they will tightly couple you with the data structure.  Bad stuff for an enterprise type of application.

Comment: My answer actually relates to moving your `GetByXXX` out of your repositories.  With WCF you are going to have data contracts anyway so you would need some mapping at the integration layer.

Answer (score 0):

Repositories are better suited for supporting operations that change state. Even when you're fetching an aggregate through a Repository, it is because you intend to change the state and persist it back right away:

```cs
var entity = repository.Get(id);
entity.ChangeSomeState();
repository.Save(entity);
```

In that scenario, `Get` returns an aggregate that is ready for modification (e.g. attached to the context if using EF, or session in NHibernate). The focus here is **consistency**.

Now, for queries you are better off with a Query class, which will support read-only scenarios and with a focus on **performance**.

All your `GetByXXX` will live in the Query class. You can even create specialized Query classes, e.g. one for Admin queries, another for Customer queries, and so on.

For extra info, have a look at these articles:

[Command and Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs)

[CQRS with MediatR in ASP.NET Core 3.1 – Ultimate Guide](https://www.codewithmukesh.com/blog/cqrs-in-aspnet-core-3-1/)